# Nesting promises with $http in AngularJS 1.0.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m trying to understand how promises work in Angular 1.0.7, but the syntax and the concept are difficult to me. I created a related previous post [Nesting promises with $resources in AngularJS 1.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329186/nesting-promises-with-resources-in-angularjs-1-0-7) that is working fine. However, when I try to do the same but replacing the `$resource` with an `$http` service, then it´s not working for me as expected.

The code never wait for the promise to come and I don´t get any result.

I attach the code:

```
// URL has to be parsed to get the destination, language and boatType       
var parseURL = function() {
    var language = $routeParams.language;
    var url = $location.path();

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    promise.then(function success(result) {
        var destination = result;
        console.log("destination:" + destination);
        searchBoats(destination);
    });

    parseDestination(url, language).then(deferred.resolve);
};
parseURL();

var parseDestination = function(url, language) {
    console.log("parseDestination.begin");
    var departure = UrlService.parseUrlDeparture(url);

    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        promise = deferred.promise;
    TranslationService.getTranslatedDeparture(departure, language, API_SERVER_URL, deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
    return promise;
};


// The function in the service
getTranslatedDeparture: function(destination, language, api) {
    var defered = $q.defer();
    var destinationPromise = defered.promise;
    $http.get("http://" + api + "/translatedDepartures?departure=" + destination + ";lang=" + language + ";matchStart=" + true).then(
        //var destination = result.data.map(function (source) { return source.element_translation; });
        defered.resolve
    );
    return destinationPromise;
}
```

Comment: To use angular 1.0.7 should not be a problem. We have a whole big website developed on it and it´s working perfectly. According to your second point, we are trying to re-factor the code, because we have many dependencies and many functions that are not following the single responsability rule. So, can you provide a working example that meets this rule?

Comment: To migrate to a newer version of Angular is not an option this moment. There should be a softer approach to this problem, don´t you think?

Comment: @Claies The question is in no way specific to Angular 1.0.7, so I don't see anything detrimental in answering it.

Comment: I agree with you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using promises wrong in just about every way imaginable. Promises are intended to be chained and create new promises using `.then()`. And doing this will fix your bugs and cut the length of your code in half. As long as you have a promise to start with (which you do because `$http.get` returns a promise), you don't need, and shouldn't use, `$q.defer()`:

```
// URL has to be parsed to get the destination, language and boatType       
var parseURL = function() {
    var language = $routeParams.language;
    var url = $location.path();

    parseDestination(url, language)
        .then(function (result) {
            var destination = result;
            console.log("destination:", destination);
            searchBoats(destination);
        });    
};
parseURL();

var parseDestination = function(url, language) {
    console.log("parseDestination.begin");
    var departure = UrlService.parseUrlDeparture(url);

    return TranslationService.getTranslatedDeparture(departure, language, API_SERVER_URL);    
};


// The function in the service
getTranslatedDeparture: function(destination, language, api) {
    var url = "http://" + api + "/translatedDepartures?departure=" + destination + ";lang=" + language + ";matchStart=" + true;

    return $http.get(url)
        .then(function (result) { return result.data; });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful example. I love people who try to explain the problem and add a working example. However, my code is not working, I get Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in this line: parseDestination(url, language).then(function (result) {. Is it related to my angular version?

Comment: @Rober Did you copy the code exactly as it's written without any changes? I don't see a way that `parseDestination()` could complete without an error but for there to be an error at the point you are describing.

Comment: Should I create a promise with $q.defer if instead of $http I have a $resource? Could you please confirm if the solution in this post is ok? Or I´m in the same anti-pattern problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329186/nesting-promises-with-resources-in-angularjs-1-0-7